# What is DomHelper in google closure?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-closure

Could somebody explain what is the meaning of DomHelper in google closure?

What is it for and how it may be useful?

Thanks!

**edit:** [Here is a more detailed answer](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/c0b5426289e9f16)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DomHelper` offers similar functionality to that provided by static utility methods within `goog.dom`. The difference is that a `DomHelper` instance can be bound to a `document` object corresponding to a different window, such as an IFrame, or the parent frame. This basically allows UI controls to conduct their DOM manipulations within the confines of the correct window, even if the actual objects live in another.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to [goog.dom.DomHelper](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_dom_DomHelper.html) - it looks like it provides an efficient, cross-browser solution to DOM manipulation.

Comment: thanks. there's dom_helper optional parameter everywhere, what is it for?

Comment: turns out it's a reference to an alternative dom object that javascript has access to - like the one from another frame

Comment: it's not necessary if you have a single frameless page